# In Google Tag Manager, getting, "Expected a string value for field: "contentGroup1". but found: "object"

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to set up a content grouping. WordPress is pushing the blog tags into the data layer as pageAttributes. I've got a custom data layer variable in GTM reading this and labeled as blogTagsArray. I used this variable in a tag to set up the content grouping, firing on blog pages. When I debug, everything is firing, but I get an error message:

Expected a string value for field: "contentGroup1". but found: "object".

Is there a second step I need to take to convert the object into a string? Or is there something I can do in this step to correct this?

Comment: Can you please post screenshot of what this object looks like?

Comment: Evidently you already knew that this was not a string, else you probably would not have called this "blogTagsArray".  From the name I assume that this is a simple list of tags, so I suggest you do a custom javascript variable with function() { return {{blogTagsArray}}.join(","); } which would make an comma separated string of tags from your dataLayer variable (YMMV, this is just an educated guess.I don't know the actual array). Google Analytics does not accept complex variables as parameters (basically it takes strings and numbers), that's why GTM is complaining.